# iText for Android -error from PdfReader and org.bouncycastle

Tags: android, itext

I am writing an Android app which needs to read a pdf file from the sdcard.  I am trying to use iText to read an image.

```
public class ExtractImages {

/** The new document to which we've added a border rectangle. */
public static final String RESULT = "results/part4/chapter15/Img%s.%s";

/**
 * Parses a PDF and extracts all the images.
 * @param src the source PDF
 * @param dest the resulting PDF
 */
public void extractImages(String filename)
    throws IOException, DocumentException {
    PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(filename);
    PdfReaderContentParser parser = new PdfReaderContentParser(reader);
    MyImageRenderListener listener = new MyImageRenderListener(RESULT);
    for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {
        parser.processContent(9, listener);
    }
    reader.close();
}
```

Iam working in Eclipse with an emulator, when I step through the code and trigger the PdfReader = new PdfReader line I get the following error in logcat:-

Could not find class 'org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder' referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj

I have the itext jar installed and being found for the imports so I am wondering if there is some other library needed.  I am using the JavaSDK 1.6.   This is the first time I have tried to use iText and it is the Community download. There must be an answer to this, I hope someone can respond.

Comment: Hello Mr. Will, this question is construction as "Ron" is asking that how to remove/solve the error/bug stating::  Could not find class 'org.bouncycastle.cert.X509CertificateHolder' referenced from method com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfReader.readDecryptedDocObj at the time of using iText jar of xyz version. Please, reopen it.

Answer (score 1):

iText cannot be directly used on Android in most cases. We've made a port with Android and App Engine specific changes. One of these changes is the use of SpongyCastle instead of BouncyCastle.

You can download a trial version here:
http://demo.itextsupport.com/newslicense/